# Visitor Pattern "does not implement interface" error

Tags: c#, design-patterns, visitor-pattern

It's first time that I try to implement the visitor pattern (using c#), I'm sorry if I did something wrong! However, I implemented this visitor pattern:

```
public interface VisitableElement
{
    void accept (VisitorElement visitor); 
}

public interface VisitorElement
{
    void visit (VisitableElement visitable);
}

public class SomeClass : VisitableElement
{
    ...
    public void accept(VisitorElement visitor)
    {
        ...
    }
}
//here there are other classes which implement VisitableElement (not useful for the example)

class Visitor: VisitorElement
{
...
    public void visit (SomeClass someobject)
    {
        ...
    }
//othes implementation of visit (one for each element of class of the hierarcy)
...
}
```

But when I try to compile this error is returned:

```
Error   1   'Visitor' does not implement interface member 'NameSpace.VisitorElement.visit(NameSpace.VisitableElement)'
```

...But why? I implemented it through visit(SomeClass someobject)!

The funny thing is that if I try to add:

```
    public void visit(VisitableElement visitable)
    {
        this.visit(visitable);
    }
```

Then everything works fine, but it should be unecessary to implement it in this way (and the first visit method should be enough!)

Comment: what is 'NotUsefulStuff'?

Comment: You have not shown the definition of the NotUsefulStuff class.  It's hard to help without seeing that.

Comment: check the Signature of VisitorElement interface's Visit method, it accepts VisitableElement  not SomeClass.  Your Visitor Class implementing VisitableElement Interface .

Comment: I guess the class `Visitor` is called `NotUsefulStuff` in your real code. Either way, the exception message does not match the code you posted. Maybe you want to correct it.

Comment: Sorry about that, I edited it (`NotUsefulStuff` = `Visitor`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The interface `VisitorElement` requires that your class implements the method `void visit (VisitableElement visitable)`.

The `visit` method you implemented does not fulfill this requirement, since it only allows arguments of type `SomeClass`.

While each `SomeClass` is a `VisitableElement`, the interface requires that the method accepts any type that implements `VisitableElement`, not only `SomeClass`.

---

If you want your `visit` method to only accept arguments of type `SomeClass`, consider using a generic `VisitorElement<T>` and an explicit interface implementation:

```
public interface VisitableElement
{
    void accept (VisitorElement visitor); 
}

public class SomeClass : VisitableElement
{
    public void accept(VisitorElement visitor) { }
}

public interface VisitorElement
{
    void visit (VisitableElement visitable);
}

public interface VisitorElement<T> : VisitorElement where T : VisitableElement
{
    void visit (T visitable);
}

class Visitor: VisitorElement<SomeClass>
{
    public void visit (SomeClass someobject) { }

    void VisitorElement.visit(VisitableElement visitable) { }
}
```

This way, you can only call the `visit (SomeClass someobject)` overload as long as you don't cast your `Visitor` instance to the non-generic `VisitorElement`. In the non-generic `visit` method, you could try to cast `visitable` to `SomeClass` and call the generic version as fallback (or do whatever you like).

---

As it is not entirely clear to me what you want to achieve, it's hard to say what is the best thing to do in your case.

Comment: Mmmh I think that you're right (about why the error appears) but do you think that my solution solves the problem (I'm talking about the implementation of `visit (VisitableElement visitable)` on the bottom of the post) ?

Comment: Sure, if you just implement the method than it obviously works. That's what the error message tells you :-)